# How to solve duplicate logic in a microservice stack

Tags: api-design

I have designed a microservice stack with docker as backbone, about 50 services in total so far, still growing...
Everything works well, happy with the design choice, but room for improvement. I notice a lot of duplicate logic in the different services for instance. Most of these duplication is related to queries to services outside the stack, such as `MySQL` or `Elastic Search` -queries, or different `REST API`'s, etc...

My idea is to refactor the design by setting up a gateway layer/api. The API would only be exposed in the private network. It would be a component that handles all gateway mappings, so when a developer needs to persist an entity, he calls the endpoint on the API that will store the entity where and how it's suppose to. We have, say, about 10 different persistence solutions as it is, also growing. I need to support multiple solutions due to the domain I'm working in.

I can see benefits with a gateway layered design as we can refactor the persistence solutions more freely.

On the downside, I see the coupling where all services depends on 1 service.

Is it a good idea to create a central point in the microservice stack, as the gateway layer would be? Would you do the same / Do you do the same? Any arguments for or against that I don't see? Any better name suggestion then `gateway` layer?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a common confusion regarding the meaning of "duplication". If some specific logic is implemented once, but deployed several times as an autonomous component, what you are actually doing is to reuse that component, not duplicating it. So it is perfectly fine for me to implement that logic in a well defined component and "use" this component in several services, but not behind its own centralised API.

Comment: Then when I need to refactor the persistence solution I need to change it everywhere, and you consider this a better approach? Is that because you prefer slimmer dependencies? Or what's the benefit?

Comment: @DanielVasquez: Can you expand on your answer? I think you are on to something, we could use a little more detail.

Comment: @superhero You may be assuming you want to refactor the persistence solution for *every* service, all at once. It may be the case that you come across a use case where you *don't* want all the services using the same persistence solution (maybe a set of SQL tables makes sense for half your services, but the other half would be much better served with a NoSQL solution)..

Comment: @Delioth I wouldn't say, I understand that I wont have to update everything at once. But if I make a change in a table, that change needs to be updated everywhere. If I use an API for this, it will be updated everywhere at once, I can also work in version to allow 2 behaviors for the same endpoint. I could ofc have a code repository that works the same way, the issue then becomes language dependency. The stack is primarily built in 3 different languages, no idea how it will look in the future, more or less languages in the stack...

Comment: You don't need to update it everywhere as you may use different versions. In that case you would need to deal with versioning. This is a common issue in microservices and it is up to the team to evaluate the trade-offs. 
The point is to evaluate if you really need to add a layer of indirection for calls that you will be making anyway from the client code. If it is matter of "not duplicating logic" I would choose using components over new deployable services.

Comment: @DanielVasquez Yes I agree that this matter is more then just "duplicate code" as the title stated. But I disagree that I wouldn't have to change the same query to do an insert if a column name or table has changed. I'm sure you see the same in that context, but that you referring to something else. I would how ever ask for a clarification on why you wouldn't prefer a deployed service over a component. I struggle to see the why a component would be preferable.